# Only Display Component for Some Routes - React

Tags: reactjs

I am developing a website in React with a login interface. The website displays a custom Navigation component, however I don't want it to display on the home route (i.e. the login page), but from what I understand, static components don't re-render on route changes, is that accurate?

I am using React-Router to handle all routing.

Here is what my App.js looks like now:

```
render() {
   return (
       <Router className="App">
          <Header />
          <NavigationBar />
          <div id="container">
          <Route path="/" exact component={LoginPage}/>
          <Route path="/EventInfo" component={EventInfo}/>
          <Route path="/RSVP" component={RSVP}/>
          <Route path="/Attendance" component={Attendance}/>
          <Route path="/Confirmation" component={Confirmation}/>
          <Route path="/Contact" component={Contact}/>
          <Route path="/Lodging" component={Lodging}/>
        </div>
     </Router>
   );
};
```

Comment: try my solution below and let me know if you need any further details :)

Answer (score 5):

That's correct. As currently constructed, your `<NavigationBar />` would display at all times. What you can do is isolate the `Routes` that use NavigationBar to their own component.

So try something like:

```
import { Switch, Router, Route } from "react-router-dom"; // fixed "

render() {
   const AuthenticatedRoutes = () => {
       return (
          <NavigationBar />
          <div id="container">
               <Switch>
                   <Route path="/EventInfo" component={EventInfo}/>
                   <Route path="/RSVP" component={RSVP}/>
                   <Route path="/Attendance" component={Attendance}/>
                   <Route path="/Confirmation" component={Confirmation}/>
                   <Route path="/Contact" component={Contact}/>
                   <Route path="/Lodging" component={Lodging}/>
              </Switch>
          </div>
       )
   }

   return (
       <Router className="App">
           <Header />
               <Switch>
                   <Route path="/" exact component={LoginPage}/>
                   <Route component={AuthenticatedRoutes}/>
               </Switch>
       </Router>
   );
};
```

In our new `Router` definition, the `Header` component will be displayed at all times.
The important thing here is to understand the `Switch` component. It will render the first `Route` whose path matches the URL provided. So if the URL is `"/"` we will display only the `Header` and `LoginPage`.

But, let's say now we navigate to the URL `"/EventInfo"`. Now, no path was matched in the outer `Switch` defined in our `Router`, so we render the `AuthenticatedRoutes` component. The same pattern is executed, now we display `NavigationBar` at all times and `react-router-dom` will execute the inner `Switch` to find a `Route` whose path matches the URL provided. Thus rendering the `EventInfo` component as well.

This structure is very useful for toggling the display of `authenticated` and `unauthenticated` components.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your response, I modified my code to reflect the changes you had made, however the the styling (caused by the div with the id "container") was affected. I was wondering if there was any way to apply the same style to both the login page and the AuthenticateRoute components? I tried surrounding the LoginPage Route in a div with the class "container" and modified the other div to set "container" as it's class rather than id. Was hoping to keep all of the main content consistent and easy to modify, rather than having to make several changes for consistency.

Comment: @Sal, that's interesting, y'know I'm not sure of an easy workaround to that. Easiest way would be to just wrap your Login component in a container class as well. That works, but I know you want to make things a bit easier to modify :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
render() {
  return (
    <Router className="App">
      <Header />
      <div id="container">
        <Route path="/" exact component={LoginPage} />
        <Route path="/blah">
          <NavigationBar />
          <Route path="/blah/EventInfo" component={EventInfo} />
          <Route path="/blah/RSVP" component={RSVP} />
          <Route path="/blah/Attendance" component={Attendance} />
          <Route path="/blah/Confirmation" component={Confirmation} />
          <Route path="/blah/Contact" component={Contact} />
          <Route path="/blah/Lodging" component={Lodging} />
        </Route>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

Comment: Hi Sreeram, thanks for your answer. I was hoping to only go one level into the url, i.e. /EventInfo rather than /blah/EventInfo, do you know of anyway to do that?

Answer (score 0):

in NavigationBar.js you can do like this

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

function NavigationBar() {
  const location = useLocation();
  const path = location.pathname;
  const [display, setDisplay] = useState(
    path !== "/" ? true : false
  );

  return (
    <>
      {display && (
        <div>
          
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
}

export default NavigationBar;
```